# Image upload in a form

Tags: node.js, angular6, mean-stack

I have an angular form with text fields and want to add am option for uploading image in the same form. I'm stuck with the latter.

The angular form contains html tag to upload the file. Once the file is uploaded the uploaded file's name is displayed in the input field.

```
<!--blog.html-->
<!--form to create new blog--> 

    <form #blogForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="Save(blogForm);">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Blog Title</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" maxlength="45" name="title" ngModel #blogtitle="ngModel"  required placeholder="Blog Title">
                      <span class="required" *ngIf="blogtitle.errors?.required && (blogtitle.dirty||blogtitle.touched||blogtitle.untouched)">*required</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Blog </label>
                      <textarea class="textarea form-control" maxlength="150" name="summary" [(ngModel)]="summary">
                        Blog</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Blog Desc</label>
                      <textarea class="textarea form-control" name="description" ngModel #blogdescription="ngModel" required>Blog Description</textarea>
                      <span  class="required" *ngIf="blogdescription.errors?.required && (blogdescription.dirty||blogdescription.touched||blogdescription.untouched)">*required</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>HashTags</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" name="hashtag" [(ngModel)]="hashtag" placeholder="hashtags">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="custom-file">
    <!--file upload -->
                        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input form-control-lg" name="file" id="customFile"
                         value="imageFile.name" (change)="handleImageFileInput($event)">
                        <input type="text" readonly="true"  [value]="imageFile" class="custom-file-label"  >
                        <button  type="button" (click)="upload()">Upload</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="button" class="btn-default" (click)="Save(blogForm)" value="Create">
                  </form>

//blog.ts
//function to create  new blog 

    Save(blogForm: any) {

        if (blogForm.valid === true)  {
          blogForm = blogForm.value;
          blogForm.userId = this.user_id;
          blogForm.author = this.display_name;
          window.confirm('Want to Publish?');
          this.blogservice.Save(blogForm).subscribe(response => {
          window.alert('Blog published successfully');
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
          });
        }
      }

//function to display selected image in the input field


    handleImageFileInput(event) {
        const img1 =event.target.files[0];
        const img =event.target.files[0].name;
        const fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
        const fileCount = fileList.length;
        if (fileCount > 0) {
          const file = fileList.item(0);
          console.log(` image file: ${file.name}`);
          console.log(img1);

          if(img == undefined) {
           this.imageFile = 'Upload an image';
         } else {
         this.imageFile = img;
         }
      }

    }
```

Need to save file along with form submission

Comment: Where do you want to save it ? Most of the time, `event.target.files[0]` is enough to upload file somewhere.

Comment: @DataHearth I'm trying to upload and save file in the blog collection in mongodb

Comment: You could save the file in a folder in your app directory and then save the file name from `event.target.files[0].name` into a property in your MongoDB collection.

Comment: still image doesn't get saved right.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JavaScript script which will read your data from input and display it :

```
<input type='file' accept='image/*' onchange='openFile(event)'><br>
<img id='output'>
<script>
  var openFile = function(event) {
    var input = event.target;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
      var dataURL = reader.result;
      var output = document.getElementById('output');
      output.src = dataURL;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  };
</script>
```

It come from the documentation of [FileReader](https://www.javascripture.com/FileReader).
With that you should be able to store the `input` wherever you want and store the path inside of your MongoDB collection.
Else if you want to use Angular plugins, here's  one that could be useful for you :
[angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)

Comment: thanks for the reply this js code wont work in my angular

Comment: So you should check the angular plugin.

Comment: I have tried  angular plugin before never got it right